# How Can I Know The Registered Devices In My GCM Application Cloud (List Devices)

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

1- let's Say I've Create A GCM Application In A Google Apis Console ...

How Can I List And View All The Devices Are Registered In My Application Cloud

To Perform An A Random Action Like Send A Push Notification to them ?

---

2- Should I Create A database to Store The Registration IDs Returned By Registered Devices 
If I Use My Own Server Like (Asp.net)

---

Comment: Try to improve quality of your question with more details and please read GCM documentation on Android Developer website.

Comment: @codingcrow
I read the `GCM documentation` more than 3 Times But I've some points I Don't Understand them yet :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> How Can I List And View All The Devices Are Registered In My Application Cloud

There is no GCM call to do this. Your app needs to tell your server the IDs to use for GCM broadcasts to that app on that device, and your server then needs to store that data somewhere.

> Should I Create A database to Store The Registration IDs Returned By Registered Devices If I Use My Own Server Like (Asp.net)

A database would seem like a fine choice.

Comment: That means I should create A database in my own server , so when a device register in the cloud and receive `registrationID` from the GCM
send it back to the server to store it in the database ,,
and when i need to send a notification I've to loop Over All registrationIDs and send a notification to them

Comment: @lo2i: Yes, that is correct. http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html See "Handling Registration Results" and "Role of the 3rd-party Application Server".

Comment: I wrote a blog post that describes how this works in general: http://blog.andromo.com/2012/how-does-airbop-push-messaging-work/ just substitute your server for the AirBop servers in the diagrams. Also you can send messages to blocks of 1000 registration Ids at a time, which is more efficient than one at a time.